# jQuery appended table adds closing tag at the end of the text automatically. Why?

Tags: jquery, html, json, html-table, append

```
$('#all_locations').append("<table>");
$('#all_locations').append("<tr><th>City</th></tr>");

$.each(data, function(i, item){
    $('#all_locations').append("<tr>");
    $('#all_locations').append("<td>"+item.city+"</td>");
    $('#all_locations').append("<tr>");
}

$('#all_locations').append("</table>");
```

Output gotten using `alert($('#all_locations').html());`

```
<table></table>
<tr><th>City</th></tr>
<tr></tr><td>Seattle</td>
<tr></tr><td>Chicago</td>
```

This code fires when ajax call is finished. Any ideas why is it doing so?

Assume that data variable is the valid JSON object.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Despite the abstraction that jQuery offers, you are operating on **elements** in the DOM, not tags in the HTML source.

`jQuery('<table>')` is shorthand for `jQuery(document.createElement('table'))`.

You need to append your table rows to the table, not to the container (and likewise, the cells need to be added to the rows).

Comment: wow didn't know that.. it does make sense though, because whenever I don't close the tag inside of append(), it would do it for me... Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

It's best practice to create a string of your HTML to append and run one `.append()` call on that string:

```
//declare our output variable
var output = '<table><tr><th>City</th></tr>';

//iterate through data
$.each(data, function(i, item){

    //add to output variable
    output += '<tr><td>' + item.city + '</td></tr>';
}

//append the output to the DOM
$('#all_locations').append(output);
```

It's pretty common to see people pushing items into an array and joining that array for the append:

```
//declare our output variable (array)
var output = ['<table><tr><th>City</th></tr>'];

//iterate through data
$.each(data, function(i, item){

    //add to output variable
    output.push('<tr><td>' + item.city + '</td></tr>');
}

//append the output to the DOM after joining it together into a string
$('#all_locations').append(output.join(''));
```

Comment: In some browsers, it's even faster to build an array of strings and concatenate them all at once before `.append`ing it to the DOM.

Comment: Are you aware of which browsers are faster at either process?

Comment: I've been trying to find the quirksmode article that measured it by browser, but can't. IIRC it was mostly older browsers that showed improvement, though.

Comment: Thanks @Jasper. That's what I was gonna do, but I wanted to try the way I mentioned in question and it didn't work and I couldn't understand why... thanks to Quentin, I got it now ))

Answer (score 0):

Add an `id` to the tag to solve this problem.
Then add the sub element to that `id` instead of parent element.

```
$(function(){

    for(var lvl=0;lvl<5;lvl++)
    {
        $("#tblId tbody").append("<tr id="+lvl+"/>");                   
        for(var fchr=0;fchr<3;fchr++)
            $("#tblId tbody #"+lvl).append("<td>Val"+lvl+fchr+"</td>");
    }

    alert($('#tblId').html());

});
```

Running example, see here:
http://jsfiddle.net/WHscf/1/

Answer (score -1):

Instead of doing it that way, try something like this:

```javascript
var table = $("<table>");
if (table){
    table.append($("<tr>").append($("<th>").text("City")));
    $.each(data, function(i, item){
        table.append($("<tr>").append($("<td>").text(item.city)));
    });
    table.appendTo($("#all_locations"));
}
```

Here's another way that's closer to how you're currently doing it:

```javascript
$("#all_locations""#all_locations").append("<tr><th>City</th></tr>"); 

$.each(data, function(i, item){  
    $('#all_locations').append("<tr>");  
    $('#all_locations').append("<td>""<tr><td>" + item.city + "</td>"td></tr>");  
    $('#all_locations').append("<tr>"});  
} 

$("#all_locations tr").wrapAll("<table></table>");
```

Comment: That last line will wrap around the `#all_locations` element, not its contents. Why not append the table to `#all_locations` first, and then append the rows to the table?