# HOw to insert plain HTML after element with JQuery

Tags: jquery, html, insert

I need to insert a piece of HTML before an element using JQuery or JS. The piece of HTML that needs to be inserted is like this `"</ul><ul class="list-inline item">"` in exactly that order.

So, this is what I am doing is:

```
$('.element').before('</ul><ul class="list-inline item">');
```

The problem is that JQuery is not inserting the HTML exactly as I write it, but rather creating an element  before the element which is an expected behavior, but not what I need in this case.

What I want to do is to insert EXACTLY that piece of HTML.

Is there any way in JQUERY or plain JS to do that?

EDIT:

I assume then, that once the HTML builds the DOM I cannot manipulate it but as elements and objetcs. What I am trying to do, is to split an ul list into two. Having a ul with 10 elements, I would like to transform it in two ul with 5 elements each, the first five li elements and the second 5 li elements. Any idea in how to achieve this?

Thnks

Comment: Please show us the HTML

Comment: That's not how DOM works, you can't insert opening and closing tag separately.

Comment: to second @undefined's comment, there would be problems in your DOM and it would be rendered differently on various browsers.

Comment: Why are you trying to close a ul then open one?  Wherever the original <ul> is you may want to look into jQuerys wrap and wrap that ul so that it gets closed properly.

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery appended table adds closing tag at the end of the text automatically. Why?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8084687/jquery-appended-table-adds-closing-tag-at-the-end-of-the-text-automatically-why)

Comment: Insert the new `ul`. Append each of the `li`s that you want to move to it.

Comment: _"What I am trying to do, is to split an ul list into two. Having a ul with 10 elements, I would like to transform it in two ul with 5 elements each, the first five li elements and the second 5 li elements."_ You should probably re-write your question and start with this.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comments, you want to split an unordered list of elements into two lists of five elements.

You can do that with this:

```
$('li').unwrap();
$('li:lt(5)').wrapAll('<ul>');
$('li:gt(4)').wrapAll('<ul>');
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/e4jhV/)**

That will convert this:

```
<ul>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
    <li>4</li>
    <li>5</li>
    <li>6</li>
    <li>7</li>
    <li>8</li>
    <li>9</li>
    <li>10</li>
</ul>
```

into this:

```
<ul>
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
    <li>4</li>
    <li>5</li>
</ul>
<ul>
    <li>6</li>
    <li>7</li>
    <li>8</li>
    <li>9</li>
    <li>10</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: That is closer, still it is not as dynamic as I need. Because I won-t know the number of elements, so, if the original list is 20 elements and the number is 5, then I should split it in 4 separated lists, so, in this case I cannot use those selectors. Any other idea?